# Change Padding of a GradientDrawable

Tags: android, padding, android-drawable

I have this layer list:

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/outer_satop_btn">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/bottom_satop_btn">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/satopButtonColor2" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/top_satop_btn">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/satopButtonColor" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want change the padding bottom of outer_satop_btn programatically but i didn't find anything for do that:

```
LayerDrawable bgDrawable = (LayerDrawable)v.getBackground();
final GradientDrawable shape1 = (GradientDrawable)   bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.outer_satop_btn);
Rect padding = new Rect();
shape1.getPadding(padding);
```

How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it in an [InsetDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html): `InsetDrawable(shape1, 0, 5, 0, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

As a drawable it has to be put on a ImageView for example.

You have to put the padding on the view that draws it.

Code example if using LinearLayout as imageViews parent:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setDrawable(shape1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams prms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
prms.setPadding(LEFT,UP,RIGHT,BOTTOM);
linearLayout.addView(img,prms);
```

Hope this helps.